# Does bazel support public.xml when build an android project

Tags: bazel

I'm migrating from gradle, and I'm using [public.xml](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html#PrivateResources) on my android project, it works fine with gradle, but when I build it with bazel, it failed with the following error:

`Error: /var/folders/th/cxy34j2x0vq9zzdh8qstx5jr0000gn/T/android_resources_tmp2185237642135735709/merged_resources/values/values.xml:6772: error: Public symbol drawable/skin_at declared here is not defined.
Error: /var/folders/th/cxy34j2x0vq9zzdh8qstx5jr0000gn/T/android_resources_tmp2185237642135735709/merged_resources/values/values.xml:6774: error: Public symbol drawable/skin_at_click declared here is not defined.
Error: /var/folders/th/cxy34j2x0vq9zzdh8qstx5jr0000gn/T/android_resources_tmp2185237642135735709/merged_resources/values/values.xml:6776: error: Public symbol drawable/skin_face declared here is not defined.
Error: /var/folders/th/cxy34j2x0vq9zzdh8qstx5jr0000gn/T/android_resources_tmp2185237642135735709/merged_resources/values/values.xml:6778: error: Public symbol drawable/skin_face_click declared here is not defined.
Error: /var/folders/th/cxy34j2x0vq9zzdh8qstx5jr0000gn/T/android_resources_tmp2185237642135735709/merged_resources/values/values.xml:6780: error: Public symbol drawable/skin_keyboard declared here is not defined.
Error: /var/folders/th/cxy34j2x0vq9zzdh8qstx5jr0000gn/T/android_resources_tmp2185237642135735709/merged_resources/values/values.xml:6782: error: Public symbol drawable/skin_keyboard_click declared here is not defined.`

What should I do here to solve this problem?

Thanks very much for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bazel 0.4.5 (the current version at time of writing) does not support private resources and public.xml files. This is because this functionality is implemented by Gradle, not the underlying tools (aapt). There is an open feature request for Bazel to reimplement this feature of Gradle here: https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/2124.